# How can I convert a column into `NA`s with R

Tags: r

I need to convert multiple columns (all of the values in each column) in a data frame to have `NA` as their value, is this possible in R?

Comment: you can do `df[, your_cols] <- NA`

Comment: `as.data.frame(matrix(NA, 10, 5))` will create a data frame with 10 rows, 5 columns with NAs.

Answer (score 0):

You may assign `NA` to multiple columns. *Example:*

```
mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")] <- NA
head(mtcars)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4          NA  NA   NA 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag      NA  NA   NA 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710         NA  NA   NA  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive     NA  NA   NA 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout  NA  NA   NA 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant            NA  NA   NA 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a feeling it was a simple answer but for some reason everything I found was showing me how to replace NA!